# Flink first window firing

Tags: apache-flink

Given a window size of 10 seconds, watermark interval of 1 sec and slack of 5 seconds
(e.g using `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor`), when the application is first started, does this mean the first window won't trigger until 15 seconds (in order to account for the 5 second slack for all events to be included in the window processing)?

Also how does this work with the fact that windows are triggered on epoch intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first window will fire when a sufficiently large watermark arrives at the window, and this has nothing to do with how long the application has been running. Let's consider a couple of cases:

(1) If you are processing historic data, then chewing through enough data to trigger the first window may only take a fraction of a millisecond.

(2) On the other hand, if the data source becomes idle, the timestamps (and the watermarks) might never advance far enough to trigger the first window. "Why doesn't my window ever produce any results?" is a common Stack Overflow question.

But yes, if you are doing event-time processing of a continuous stream of live, near-real-time data, then the first window will fire somewhere between 5 and 15 seconds after the application starts, more or less. The windows will be aligned to the epoch, so the ending time of the first window will be anywhere up to 10 seconds after the application started, and it will take roughly another 5 seconds for the watermark to be generated. (I say "roughly" because we are mixing event time and processing time together in this scenario, which can not be done deterministically.)