# Flink Pipeline Does Not Execute When Using Group By and Window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am encountering an issue while deploying a Flink streaming application using a Kafka source. Below is my code snippet:

```
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        KafkaSource<Event> source = KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("...")
                .setTopics("events")
                .setGroupId("streamprocessor")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new EventDeserializer())
                .build();

        WatermarkStrategy<Event> eventWatermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.timestamp);

        DataStreamSource<Event> sourceEvents = env.fromSource(source,  eventWatermarkStrategy, "Kafka Source");

        DataStream<Float> aggregate = sourceEvents.filter(event -> event.property)
                .keyBy((KeySelector<Event, Object>) event -> new Tuple3<>(event.house_id, event.household_id, event.plug_id))
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .aggregate(new AggregateFunction<Event, Tuple2<Float, Integer>, Float>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Float, Integer> createAccumulator() {
                        return new Tuple2<>(0.0F, 0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Float, Integer> add(Event event, Tuple2<Float, Integer> accumulator) {
                        return new Tuple2<>(accumulator.f0 + event.value, accumulator.f1 + 1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Float getResult(Tuple2<Float, Integer> accumulator) {
                        return accumulator.f1 > 0 ? accumulator.f0 / accumulator.f1 : 0.0F;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Float, Integer> merge(Tuple2<Float, Integer> a, Tuple2<Float, Integer> b) {
                        return new Tuple2<>(a.f0 + b.f0, a.f1 + b.f1);
                    }
                });

        aggregate.print();
        LOG.info("Started stream processor");
        env.execute();
```

Even though the code runs without any errors, it seems like the aggregated data isn't making it to the print statement despite a substantial wait time. I've gone through a few checks, but I can't seem to figure out why the aggregated data isn't showing up in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly caused by something related to the watermarking. See my answer to [Flink first window firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551695/flink-first-window-firing/65553954#65553954) for some background.

You can verify that the problem is related to watermarking by changing `TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(...)` to `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(...)`. If, as I expect, this "fixes" the problem, then you'll know for sure.

To get this working with event time windowing, you'll then need to identify the cause -- which relates to not having enough data. If you have an empty or idle Kafka partitions, that would explain the problem, and you can address this by either setting an idle timeout on the watermarking strategy, or by reducing the number of partitions so that none are empty. On the other hand, perhaps your dataset doesn't extend far enough in time to justify the creation of a sufficiently large watermark. In other words, maybe the first window is still waiting to be triggered.